# Magento2 After Sync Images To Amazon S3 All Images from Magento are Deleted

Tags: magento2, media, aws, console, s3

I have create one module to sync all magento2 media  to amazon s3
but after sync to amazon s3 server my all magento media's are deleted  from my local system.
and i don't want to remove that media.
Does anyone know how i can solve this problem ?

I have create my custom command to export media

```
php bin/magento amazons3:media:export
```